# Migrating from CS50 Development Environment

Tags: development-environment, cloud9-ide

I completed all the assignments on CS50 (with a great deal of help reading stackoverflow articles, thanks!) and I'd like to migrate to a "non CS50" environment to do the final project.  I thought it would be relatively simple to move to Cloud9 since that's what the CS50 IDE is based on, but it's feeling like a pretty steep learning curve.  I've got 3 hours into just trying to figure out how to install (or use if it's already installed) the sqlitebrowser (and still no luck).

npm install sqlitebrowser... nope
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser... nope (you get the idea, on and on it goes)

Given that, this is feeling like a month-long program just to get started.

I'm assuming there must be an easier way for a beginner to get started developing web apps, but googling "migrating from CS50 IDE" and the like has a stunning dirth of information, I can't believe I'm alone in trying to figure out my next steps, so I'm a bit puzzled as to why no one else is asking.  Hopefully this is just a dumb question where I'm missing something obvious.  Or maybe this is just the way it is, you have to invest a lot of time to get your development environment going? Is there a development environment that has a community that's friendly to beginners?

In any case, I'm sure there are some on here having gone this path, so before I spend a month on this path, I figured I would at least ask!

Answer (score 0):

They mentioned Visual Studio Code at one point and it has been okay so far, but not as convenient as the CS50 IDE and a bit tricky at times.  debugger often falsely flags text. Sometimes I have to run terminal commands in a separate administrator cmd window.  Still it works.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve tried AWS since Cloud9 was what I used but I wound up on google shell because I had some friends using it and it was easier to get up and running although the noSQL firebase is quite a departure